# Android DataBinding with Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-databinding

I have been experimenting with Android Studio and DataBinding features with Kotlin. 
I am struggling with Android Studio and Observable/BaseObservable, which does not resolve `BR` references and marks them as unknown symbols.

My `build.gradle` looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "maca.playground.simpleapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1"
}
```

Gradle compiles fine, but Android Studio is complaining about unknown symbols: (User.kt)

package maca.playground.simpleapp

import android.databinding.BaseObservable
import android.databinding.Bindable

```
/**
 * Created by maca on 17/02/2018.
 */
data class User(private var _firstName: String) : BaseObservable() {
    var firstName: String
        @Bindable get() = _firstName
        set(value) {
            if (_firstName != value) {
                _firstName = value
                notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName)
            }
        }
}
```

I am trying to use `notifyPropertyChanged` but IDE is complaining about unknown field member firstName.

Is there any support for this feature?

Comment: What do you mean by "BR references"?

Comment: You can skip `generateStubs`.

Comment: Edited original question. By BR I am meaning field references when using `Observable`